How do I choose which Visual Studio components to download?
I am designing a website using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and would like to use Visual Studio instead of Notepad because I will be able to organise my files in directories and use the live server to share my code.
I have downloaded the Windows form workload to design and create a website in a similar way to the one I created for coursework at college. I have however changed my mind and decided I would like to use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to design and create the website instead.

This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.
